# How do I know if a user has my app installed and opened?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I wish to promote my app. If a user downloads an app, I would like to know if this is downloaded and opened.

How would you go around doing this?

**The question is: how would I know if the user does install my app and open it?**

Comment: check if the package name exists

Comment: Receive some goods?

Comment: I think this is being down voted for the way it is asked, I will reformat it for you, This really could be an interesting question

Comment: I am giving the clue, using Google analytics you can do it.Google analytics supports for how may installs against the app and owner can see how many users opens the app currently(Actively). or use this for how many installs and send the data to your server using API when the user installed and using it .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the key part of "downloaded and opened" is the "**and opened**" part, correct?

You could just have your activity check some database value (for example) to see if this is the first time that the user opened the app. If so, you could just call a Web Service.

You could actually do that to keep usage statistics in general; you'd probably want to have some kind of explicit opt-in from the user first, though.

Android also has a [package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html) for capturing usage statistics.